# Smooth closed Riemannian manifolds with quasi-analytic metrics

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, semi-riemannian-geometry, real-analytic-structures

I haven't found a reference for this exact definition in the literature so I wonder if what I want to pose here makes sense. I basically want to consider a smooth close Riemannian manifold that locally admits a quasi-analytic metric, and I want to define it like this.

Definition. We say that $(M,g)$ locally admits a quasi-analytic metric, if given each point $p\in M$ there is a coordinate chart $(U,\phi)$ containing the point $p$, such that in this coordinate system near the point $p$ the metric components belong to a quasi-analytic class $C^M(\phi(U))$ for some sequence $M=\{M_j\}_{j=1}^{\infty}$ that satisfies the Denjoy-Carleman classification.

Part of what makes this definition strange is that I do not require the differential structure of the manifold to be also quasi-analytic. But since for my purposes I only want to work locally in the manifold, I am thinking that the differential structure can just be assumed to be smooth and what matters is just that the metric is quasi-analytic in a coordinate system. This is kind of similar to working with a smooth manifold that has a real-analytic metric. Does this kind of definition make sense in general?

Comment: Similar to the case of analytic metrics, the harmonic functions will also be Denjoy-Carleman by Cauchy-Kovalevskaya for Denjoy-Carleman class, I think, and then in harmonic local coordinates, the transition maps will be Denjoy-Carleman, I think. So I don't think you really get anything new.